# Page number font incorrect on fancy pages

Tags: fonts, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am using fancyhdr in my report and a selected font. The page number font is correct on the pages when a new chapter starts, but it is reverts to some other font on the other pages. I think these problematic pages are the ones defined by fancy? I cannot understand why fancy gets the header font correct, but messes up with the footer page number font. I have searched a lot but cannot find the solution. Please see my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Test}
The page number font for the page where a chapter starts is correct.
\newpage
\section{Wrong font}
The page number font on this page is wrong.
\end{document}
```

Am I defining my document font correctly? If so, how can I fix the page numbering font for my fancy pages so that they are the same as the document font?

This problem occurs in a large report, so if there is a solution that is unlikely to clash with anything else it would be better.

Comment: The first page is using the `plain` page style as it is a chapter title page. By default `fancyhdr` does not touch `plain` unless you explicitly as it to. Just for fun, I switched to the `memoir` class (give it the `openany` class option and it will behave like `report`), it has its own build in header/footer interface. In `memoir` there is no issues with the fonts.

Comment: Actually, in the `fancyhdr` souece you'll find the problem, the code actually says `\fancyfoot[c]{\rmfamily\thepage}` as the default footer for the `fancy` style (the `\rmfamily` overwrites your setting). You'd probably have to tell `fancyhdr` what footer you want. That would be described in the `fancyhdr` manual.

Comment: Thanks @daleif. If you can post the answer and it works, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look in `fancyhdr.sty` we find

```
\fancyfoot[c]{\rmfamily\thepage} % page number
```

as the default code for the header of the `fancy` page style. Note the `\rmfamily`. It overrides your sans serif setting.

You can probably just add

```
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
```

or

```
\fancyfoot[c]{\sffamily\thepage}
```

to your preamble and it should work.

As mentioned, it might be easier in the long run to switch to a more high level class, like `memoir` or something from the KOMA bundle. Then you don't need so many packages to get the layout you want. Note for example that `memoir` has its own well integrated page style system, so `fancyhdr` should not be used with that class.

Comment: Thank you! `fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}` did the trick! I cannot use `memoir` as it does not seem to be compatible with my use of `\part{}` sectioning.

Comment: @NicoleAndrew please show me an example of that. `memoir` supports `\part` just fine.

Comment: @NicoleAndrew `memoir` not only supports `\part`s but also `\book`s.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point `titleps`, which comes  with `titlesec`, does not have this problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{myps}{%
\headrule
\sethead{\itshape\thesection. \MakeUppercase{\sectiontitle}}%
{}%
{\itshape\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter.\enspace\chaptertitle}}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{myps}
\chapter{Test}

The page number font for the page where a chapter starts is correct.
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Right font} The page number font on this page is right.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bernard! This causes some kind of compatibility problem in the huge report structure I'm using... I get this error  from inside : `Command \headrule already defined. \newcommand\headrule{\setheadrule{.4\p@}}`. I don't know nearly enough about LaTeX, but was hoping there might be a less 'intrusive' answer.

Comment: Probably you still load `fancyhdr`? If that's the case, you can't load both, as they tackle the same problem. Note `titleps` is easier to customise than `fancyhdr`, as it doesn't use the `marks` system by default.

Comment: I cannot find any code explicitly adding `fancyhdr`, I used grep on the whole folder, but found it in the main files log file: `main.log:(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty` Can `fancyhdr` be added by other packages somehow?

Comment: Yes, it may happen: either a package, or by your .cls file. Could you post them (or a link to)?

Comment: Is it possible that `fancyhdr` is automatically included in the `report` class that I am using? I cannot use `memoir`, as suggested in the other comments because I use `\part` dividers in my report that `memoir` doesn't seem to support.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but for now it seems much simpler to just update `fancyhdr` as suggested by @daleif. I'll consider `titleps` in the future.

Comment: No, it's not included. No standard class loads packages, nor do they define`\headrule`.